# The Pub Quiz and the Passion

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #49: Pub Quiz Camouflage](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7159/)...a day or two late.  Oops.</sup>

Your local pub has an interesting way to show their pub quiz questions--sixteen televisions in a four-by-four display.  However, when you come in today, just as the quiz is supposed to start, the quiz runner is having problems with the last television.  After they deliver some percussive maintenance to the monitor, they get a picture...but it's only a blown-up letter Z.

The runner yells out, "Oh, that's not even part of the question--oh, forget it.  They should be able to figure out what the answer is anyway."

Using the answers to the other fifteen questions and the use of one more step, what's the answer to number 16?

> 1. A rival to GarageBand and Audacity, what is the name of Adobe's digital audio workstation program?
> 2. What cultivar of rapeseed is sometimes used in biodiesel?
> 3. What South American cryptid shares its name with a "Cup" given annually to the "ugliest new building in the United Kingdom" from 2006-2018?
> 4. Also often used to describe any bee nest, what's the name of a man-made structure used to house bees?
> 5. What's defined by Merriam-Webster as "the proprietorship element in a corporation usually divided into shares?"
> 6. In the children's television show "Blue's Clues," what's the name of Mr. Salt and Mrs. Pepper's first child, first seen in the episode "Blue's News?"
> 7. In the children's television show "Rugrats," what's the name of the oldest child with the surname "Pickles?"
> 8. What does lead do at temperatures of 1750°C?
> 9. What name is both the name of the villain in the video game "Super Mario Bros. 2" and a demeaning nickname in the Disney animated movie "The Sword in the Stone?"
> 10. What four-letter word is a synonym for "heedless," "reckless," and "foolhardy?"
> 11. What liquid, when mixed with baking soda, creates the reaction seen in many junior high school volcanoes?
> 12. In chemistry, what quantity is equal to 6.02214076 times ten to the twenty-third power molecules?
> 13. With "the," what "always wins," according to a common gambling axiom?
> 14. According to the title, what is Dr. Sandra Lee known for popping on a TLC television show?
> 15. What simple children's playground game is, in the United Kingdom, also known as "tig," "it," and "dobby?"
> 16. Z

Hint:

> The answer to question seven is something of a odd woman out.  Maybe start there?

Hint 2:

> You're pronouncing "mole" wrong.

Hint 3:

> I make a fair number of questions about video games.  This is one of them.

Not-so-much-a-hint-as-just-making-the-puzzle-easier:

> Okay.  Here's a clue for question 16, in an Et tu, Etui sorta style.
> 16. What'z the name of the newzpaper comic ztrip created by Jerry Zcott and Jim Borgman?

Comment: On 3, the award's name isn't anything to do with South America. Change the question?

Comment: Upon further research the [award's name] is in fact a South American cryptid. Wikipedia has it listed as the same thing with an O instead of an E if you want to give it a look.

Comment: Ed was sorta right, the award wasn't named directly after the cryptid, so I changed the phrasing of the question a little.

Comment: Ooh that second hint was helpful... Now I'm going to have to revise my answer...

Comment: I think it's about time for another hint? :-D

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer:

> 1) Audition,
>    2) Canola,
>    3) Carbuncle,
>    4) Hive,
>    5) Stock,
>    6) Paprika,
>    7) Angelica (by @Stiv),
>    8) Boil,
>    9) Wart,
>    10) Rash,
>    11) Vinegar,
>    12) Mole,
>    13) House,
>    14) Pimple,
>    15) Tag,
>    16) Sits

> From here it's clear that we have a connect wall. I've only spotted one very large group (some of these were found by @Ed), and its:

> Carbuncle, Hives, Boil, Wart, Rash, Mole, Pimple, Tag (synonyms of welt, all 8 are skin conditions).

> Angelica is a celery, which with stock, vinegar, canola oil, paprika, and mole sauce make a large group of ingredients

> House, Hive, Stock, Boil and Tag are all nouns and verbs.

> Audition, House and Angelica are all horror movies, but I can't fit any of the other clues into that grouping.

> I think the final answer is going to be one that fits into a specific group of 4, rather than a more open category.

I'm intrigued to see if anyone can build off what I've done to solve the puzzle!

Comment: One of your answers is incorrect.

Comment: 7 should be rot13(Natryvpn) - not in the same nuclear family, but the same surname nonetheless :)

Comment: nyfb abha naq ireo: fgbpx, obvy, gnt

Comment: 16 izn't quite right.  I think you've mizzed what exactly my zubtitution waz.